# number of rows in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

is it possible to do conditional select based on a number of rows in a stored procedure?

E.g. if `select * from table1` has no records, then do `select * from table2`?

Comment: I've tried the following, but it never returns records from table2: `code SELECT * FROM table1 LIMIT 1;
SET @cnt = FOUND_ROWS();
IF cnt=0 THEN
  SELECT * FROM table2;
END IF;`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln FROM table1
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, ..., coln FROM table2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1)
```

This of course assumes that both tables have exactly the same structure.

Comment: I would prefer not to use UNION in this situation.